# Publish python script Nosetest output on Jenkins result

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nose

I am trying to add a python unit-test into the Jenkins build along with other C unit-tests. I can execute python unit-test with 
`nosetests my_py_unittest.py` and also generate JUnit result xml with 
`nosetests --with-xunit my_py_unittest.py`.

And I have access to the Jenkins' CI Jenkinsfile (for both windows and linux) only. How do I add the unit-test results from nosetests (preferably without generating xml file) to the Jenkins build? I am new to Jenkins and I could find the process of adding test via Jenkins Web portal, but not via Code in CI Jenkinsfile.

If it helps, the other results are added into the Result object with addResult method.
It would really nice, if someone could also provide template to the CI code.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? If you run the nose tests as a shell script, the output will get spit out to the console of the running pipeline job in jenkins, if the tests fail I assume the shell script returns a non-0 exit code, which will stop the pipeline. It should work just right out of the box like running any other shell script

Comment: I need to publish test report, in which if 10 tests are run by the nosetests 5 passed, 5 failed. How that test result would be published? Also, failing the test shouldn't stop build and the next tests.

Comment: Published to what? The results of the shell script will be spit out into the console, if  you need it to be sent to some service then you need to see if this is supported by nose or if you need to build your own service to do that. Other than that, you can also store the output  as an xml and then save it so that it is available in the build results in Jenkins. If you do not want want the shell script to stop the pipeline then that is also possible by for instance appending: 
|| true
to the shell script

Comment: I needed to track the results executed with nosetests. 
yes, "|| true" helped,  it allowed me to go ahead without stopping the pipeline. 
And with "junit <output_xml_from_nosetests>" allowed me to let Jenkins grab the result and track them. So, problem is solved now. Thanks